# A class of sparse matrices whose inverse is also sparse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

In general the inverse of a sparse matrix is dense. A notable (but trivial) exception from that rule are diagonal matrices. Is there any other (broad) class of sparse matrices whose inverse is also sparse?

Comment: Sparse low rank perturbations of diagonal matrices will also have sparse inverses, by the Woodbury formula.

Comment: Good point! In addition, any block-diagonal matrix would also do the trick. Any other classes?

Answer (score 3):

Orthohonal sparse matrices: The inverse is the transposed matrix and hence as sparse as the original one.